# What data from users does Stack Exchange keep?

Tags: support, gdpr

I'm from Europe, which has the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR). Does Stack Exchange have a GDPR manifest? What data from users does Stack Exchange keep?

Comment: The privacy policy describes the categories of personal information collected: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy#info-we-collect

Comment: @Smitop thank you for the answer. That privacy policy is applyed to all the sites of StackExchange?

Comment: yep, it applies to all sites

Answer (score 6):

In the footer of all pages you find a link to the [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy#info-we-collect). The policy applies to all sites, despite it being served from stackoverflow.com.

The policy has a chapter called *WHAT INFORMATION DO WE COLLECT*. It goes on to explain that the following categories of data are or might be collected.

- Identity Data
- Contact Data
- Technical Data
- Account registration information
- Billing information
- Profile information
- Information we use to identify and authenticate you
- Analytics information
- Information from Developer surveys, questionnaires, research and feedback programs
- Marketing and sales information
- Device and browser information received automatically
- Location information

The policy itself has extensive explanation of each of these categories and I'm not going to copy it all over as only the policy as published is legally binding and can change.
This answer serves more as a sign post to the formal documents.